# Greenback boogie lyrics from Suits TV series theme

Tags: grammar, lyrics

I recently started watching "Suits". There is a theme song. It has a lyrics with a sentence "Everybody wanna know, how it feel". I turned the CC and yes, its exactly that way. 
I think it should rather be "how it feel**s**".

But I'm not an native English speaker, so its possible that I simply miss something - some slang, hidden meaning. Is this a correct sentence?

Comment: Lyrics do not always follow grammar rules, anyway it may be a short for *How (does) it feel*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a grammatically correct English sentence.

It's most likely derived from [ebonics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ebonics), which has become "cool" to use in modern lyrics.

> Everybody wanna know how it feel

In the song, it means "Everybody wants to know how it feels" - which would be the correct way of saying it.